# Getting the interpolation function from a list plot

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I have conducted a chemistry experiment and obtained a list of concentrations of a reactant against time. I plot a graph of this using Mathematica's `ListPlot` functionality, as follows:

```
ListPlot[{{0, 0.562}, {10, 0.523}, {20, 0.480}, {30, 0.438}, {40, 0.398}, {50, 0.357},
 {60, 0.320}, {70, 0.285}, {80, 0.255}, {90, 0.230}, {100, 0.220}}, Joined -> True,
 InterpolationOrder -> 2, Mesh -> Full, AxesLabel -> {"Time (s)", "[A] (moldm^-3)"}]
```

This produces the graph below:

[image]

However, I wish to calculate the rate of reaction, for which I need the first derivative at $t=0$. I want to be able to get the interpolating function used by the `ListPlot` function when I specify `InterpolationOrder -> 2`, is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `f=Interpolation[data,InterpolationOrder->3]` ?

Comment: Strongly related SO question: ["In Mathematica, what interpolation function is ListPlot using?"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3864709/590388)

Comment: How to remove the points? I need a line plot only

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Like Chris says:

```
data = {{0, 0.562}, {10, 0.523}, {20, 0.480}, {30, 0.438}, {40, 0.398}, {50, 0.357}, 
        {60, 0.320}, {70, 0.285}, {80, 0.255}, {90, 0.230}, {100, 0.220}}
f = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

then

```
f'[0]
```

returns

> ```
> -0.0037
> ```

Comment: Thank you to both you and Chris for your help! :)

Comment: Is there anyway I can reclaim a function in terms of $t$ from the `InterpolatingFunction`? Thanks!

Comment: @Shaktal - Have a look at `Fit` and `FindFit`, which will give you a function for the given data, in any form you want. If you think you have a quadratic equation then `f := Fit[data, {x^2, x, 1}, x]`

Comment: @Shaktal: you'll probably want to use `FindFit[]`; it looks to me here that your reaction is following first-order kinetics, and linearization (by taking logarithms) isn't the best way to get good values for your parameters.

Answer (score 43):

Let me elaborate on @stevenvh's answer using Splines instead of Interpolation.

The danger of using `f'[0]` is that the built-in interpolation requires that the (Hermite) polynomials go through each data points.
Now if you data is noiseless that's fine, but if your data is noisy, the derivative of the interpolation will be all the more noisy (as a rule its always a bad idea to differentiate noise!).

In that case, you can either use a parametric fit (as suggested by @stevenvh) or a non-parametric fit, say, using Splines (or any parametrisation for which you can weight the relative degree of smoothness of your fit). Let me illustrate this, starting with your dataset:

```
 pts = {{0, 0.562}, {10, 0.523}, {20, 0.480}, {30, 0.438}, {40, 
0.398}, {50, 0.357}, {60, 0.320}, {70, 0.285}, {80, 0.255}, {90, 
0.230}, {100, 0.220}};
```

Let us define a noisy set:

```
 pts2 = pts + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}, Dimensions[pts]];
```

Now the original solution was to use (Hermite) interpolation;

```
 f0 = Interpolation[pts2];
```

but let's also define a Spline interpolation

```
 f = BSplineFunction[pts2];
```

Comparing the two curves

```
 Show[Graphics[{Red, Point[pts2], Green, Line[pts2]}, Axes -> True], 
 ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}], 
 Plot[f0[x], {x, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}], 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2] // Quiet;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

we can visually see that the grey curve (the Spline) provides a better representation of the derivative at the origin. Indeed

```
  f'[0] // #[[2]]/#[[1]] &
 (* -0.00365569 *)
```

is closer to the underlying value of `-0.0037`,
than the value returned by the original method (red dashed curve):

```
 f0'[0]
 (* 0.0120881 *).
```

Of course, statistically they both yield something reasonable

```
 Mean@ Table[
 pts2 = pts + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}, Dimensions[pts]];
 f = BSplineFunction[pts2 ];
 f0 = Interpolation[pts2];
 {f0'[0], f'[0] // #[[2]]/#[[1]] &}
 , {15000}] // Quiet
(* {-0.00364452,-0.00393355}  *)
```

but the RMS on the Spline solution is typically $\sim$3 times smaller;

```
 (StandardDeviation@ Table[
 pts2 = pts + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}, Dimensions[pts]];
 f = BSplineFunction[pts2 ];
 f0 = Interpolation[pts2];
 {f0'[0], f'[0] // #[[2]]/#[[1]] &}
 , {1500}] // Quiet) // #[[1]]/#[[2]] &
 (* 2.70277 *)
```

More generally, let us build on the [ref/BSplineCurve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BSplineCurve.html) Least square fitting example in the documentation. Consider the set of points:

```
 pts = Table[{i, Exp[-i] Sin[10 Pi i] + RandomReal[.3]}, {i, 0, 1, .003}];
```

Use uniform parametrization:

```
 uparam[pts_] := N[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[pts] - 1)]];
```

Define a function to generate clamped knots for a given number of control points and degrees:

```
 kfun[n_, d_] := 
 Join[ConstantArray[0, d], Range[0, 1, 1/(n - d)], ConstantArray[1, d]];
```

Define the basis matrix for least squares:

```
 mbasis[pts_, n_, d_] := 
With[{param = uparam[pts]}, 
Table[BSplineBasis[{d, kfun[n, d]}, j - 1, param[[i]]], {i, 
 Length[param]}, {j, n}]];
```

A cubic B-Spline curve with `25` control points seems reasonable here  for fitting that particular curve:

```
 ctrlpts = LeastSquares[mbasis[pts, 25, 3], pts];
```

Let me show the data with the curve:

```
 ListPlot[pts, Epilog -> {Red, BSplineCurve[ctrlpts, SplineDegree -> 3]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now the derivative at the origin is

```
 BSplineFunction[ctrlpts, SplineDegree -> 3]'[0] // #[[2]]/#[[1]] &
 (*  39.7595 *),
```

to be compared to the exact value:

```
 D[Exp[-x] Sin[10 Pi x], x] /. x -> 0 // N
 (* 31.4159 *)
```

which, given the amount of noise, is a reasonable estimate. On average, the non-parametric estimate is fine:

```
  {Mean[#], StandardDeviation[#]/Sqrt[Length[#]]} & @Table[
  pts = Table[{i, Exp[-i] Sin[10 Pi i] + 
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.1]]}, {i, 0, 1, .01}];
  ctrlpts = LeastSquares[mbasis[pts, 25, 3], pts];
   BSplineFunction[ctrlpts, SplineDegree -> 3]'[0] // #[[2]]/#[[1]] &, {100}]
```

(* {32.378,1.25732} *)

The main virtue of this second example is that we now have a control parameter, namely the number of control points, which we can adapt to the level of noise in order to get an accurate estimate of the derivative.
More generally, fitting with a variable amount of smoothing can be formalized in the context of [Maximum a Posteriori analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation). There are even methods (such as [cross validation](http://www.stat.wisc.edu/%7Ewahba/ftp1/oldie/golub.heath.wahba.pdf)) to estimate automatically what the proper amount of smoothing should be.

EDIT

As an alternative to using the number of Splines basis to control the smoothness of the curve, let us consider an [explicit penalty function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization). The idea here is that instead of solving for the best (spline) weights in the least square sense (a maximum likelihood solution solution while assuming Gaussian statistics), we find these, subject to a prior corresponding to a 'roughness' penalty (which allows us to tune how smooth the spine function should be, which involves adding a tunable cost to unsmooth spline).

```
Clear[ctrlpts];
ctrlpts[lambda_:0]:= 
With[{mat = mbasis[pts, 50, 3], 
reg = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 
    2., {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1 -> -1.}, {50, 50}, 0.]}, 
LinearSolve[Transpose[mat].mat + 10^(lambda) Transpose[reg].reg, 
Transpose[mat].(Last /@ pts)]];
```

Let us start  with an under-smooth solution (lambda=-4.25)

```
Show[ListPlot[pts, AxesLabel -> font[] /@ {x, y}], 
ListLinePlot[{First /@ pts, mbasis[pts, 50, 3].ctrlpts[-4.25]} // Transpose,
PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that the red curve seems to somewhat over fit the noise for this value of lambda.

Now let us put more weights on our penalty using `ctrlpts[0.25]`

```
 Show[ListPlot[pts, AxesLabel -> font[] /@ {x, y}], 
 ListLinePlot[{First /@ pts, mbasis[pts, 50, 3].ctrlpts[0.25]} // Transpose,
 PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Better?

As far as the estimated derivative is concerned, we can define with mathematica the derivative of our spline basis

```
Clear[dbasis];
dbasis[pts_, n_, d_] := 
With[{param = uparam[pts]}, 
Table[Release[D[BSplineBasis[{d, kfun[n, d]}, j - 1, x], x]] /. 
 x -> param[[i]], {i, Length[param]}, {j, n}]];
```

and watch how changing the weight of the penalty changes the roughness of the derivative

```
{ListLinePlot[{First /@ pts, dbasis[pts, 50, 3].ctrlpts[-6]}//Transpose, PlotStyle -> Blue],
 ListLinePlot[{First /@ pts, dbasis[pts, 50, 3].ctrlpts[0.15]}//Transpose,PlotStyle -> Red],
 Plot[D[Exp[-x] Sin[10 Pi x], x] // Release, {x, 0, 1},PlotStyle -> {Dashed,Green}]} // Show
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that the derivative at the origin is still available via

```
 BSplineFunction[ctrlpts[0.25], SplineDegree -> 3]'[0]
```

and more generally e.g. the second derivative

```
  df[x_] = BSplineFunction[ctrlpts[0.25], SplineDegree -> 3]''[x]
```

In closing, [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization) on this topic is rather good.

**UPDATE 2021**

Since version 12 Mathematica has built in [regularisation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FitRegularization.html)
which is implemented for Interpolation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/218916/1089)

Comment: Oh man great answer! Learned a bunch, thanks

Answer (score 7):

To see the relevance of the comments by @chris for your data, plot the derivatives for two interpolations of your data:

```
f2 = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 2];
f3 = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3];
p = Plot[{f2'[x], f3'[x]}, {x, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
AxesLabel -> {"Time", "Rate of Reaction"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

I think that the first problem is to know the physical law between the measured parameter and the time.

For the kinetic analysis of the A vitamin via the Carr-Price reaction (absorbance vs. time), according to the Beer-Lambert law, I use  `LinearModelFit`. The intercept is the absorbance at t0.

```
model = LinearModelFit[data, x, x];
equation = Normal[model];
slope = Select[equation[[2]], # Epsilon Reals &, 1];
intercept = equation[[1]];
```