# Interpolation[] gives negative values when all the initial data is positive

Tags: interpolation

I have this data:

```
    data4[100]={{99.98`, 1.477804748224006`}, {99.98010000000001`, 
   2365.0750456414803`}, {99.98020000000001`, 
   7388.983990539655`}, {99.9803`, 12214.415228382633`}, {99.9804`, 
   14703.728757320594`}, {99.9805`, 
   13833.517124715048`}, {99.98060000000001`, 
   9910.24843752318`}, {99.9807`, 4572.062808475352`}, {99.9808`, 
   570.8108232836022`}, {99.9809`, 
   1360.4394093799826`}, {99.98100000000001`, 
   10546.858200868768`}, {99.9811`, 31276.246551027016`}, {99.9812`, 
   65650.1254789103`}, {99.9813`, 
   114254.56416369356`}, {99.98140000000001`, 
   175877.45012692566`}, {99.9815`, 247463.43115736826`}, {99.9816`, 
   324324.10569403647`}, {99.9817`, 400585.6434020496`}, {99.9818`, 
   469822.1456480918`}, {99.9819`, 525795.5336175732`}, {99.982`, 
   563205.5837321972`}, {99.9821`, 578349.5929231215`}, {99.9822`, 
   569600.9007249621`}, {99.9823`, 537638.1255371793`}, {99.9824`, 
   485389.5506534906`}, {99.9825`, 417695.34242114425`}, {99.9826`, 
   340728.91596566234`}, {99.9827`, 261252.42488402053`}, {99.9828`, 
   185805.19866843504`}, {99.9829`, 119934.45681939927`}, {99.983`, 
   67573.04382586862`}, {99.98310000000001`, 
   30649.601122680797`}, {99.98320000000001`, 
   8984.93375823133`}, {99.98330000000001`, 
   488.57590847085385`}, {99.9834`, 1627.1205800512662`}, {99.9835`, 
   8096.737603320689`}, {99.98360000000001`, 
   15602.028881503466`}, {99.98370000000001`, 
   20626.473373518827`}, {99.9838`, 21078.87118582859`}, {99.9839`, 
   16715.90414629784`}, {99.98400000000001`, 
   9271.330417955402`}, {99.98410000000001`, 
   2263.4817347905678`}, {99.9842`, 499.00930637276855`}, {99.9843`, 
   9335.824909593328`}, {99.98440000000001`, 
   33805.42443036627`}, {99.98450000000001`, 
   77718.79959836493`}, {99.9846`, 142887.136511969`}, {99.9847`, 
   228577.00679417455`}, {99.9848`, 331290.87329430395`}, {99.9849`, 
   444921.04587067786`}, {99.985`, 561274.3394688623`}, {99.9851`, 
   670912.5821721719`}, {99.9852`, 764208.0275593415`}, {99.9853`, 
   832479.363953682`}, {99.9854`, 869058.3616487961`}, {99.9855`, 
   870142.0041714903`}, {99.9856`, 835310.0610613178`}, {99.9857`, 
   767630.5596346757`}, {99.9858`, 673329.9921983734`}, {99.9859`, 
   561064.1071001278`}, {99.986`, 
   440880.5960885422`}, {99.98610000000001`, 
   323009.09572123486`}, {99.98620000000001`, 
   216640.19370923933`}, {99.98630000000001`, 
   128859.40940812681`}, {99.9864`, 63883.29183825436`}, {99.9865`, 
   22704.86291029975`}, {99.98660000000001`, 
   3199.7311446716553`}, {99.98670000000001`, 
   679.7731520971815`}, {99.9868`, 8817.201777734488`}, {99.9869`, 
   20807.144107481454`}, {99.98700000000001`, 
   30599.608320206604`}, {99.98710000000001`, 
   34017.603224111605`}, {99.9872`, 29589.91591126962`}, {99.9873`, 
   18963.736616762995`}, {99.98740000000001`, 
   6819.466464542636`}, {99.98750000000001`, 
   280.1958293620077`}, {99.9876`, 7881.952610961169`}, {99.9877`, 
   38237.52969319436`}, {99.98780000000001`, 
   98576.85395021607`}, {99.9879`, 193372.72190030565`}, {99.988`, 
   323257.87767462275`}, {99.9881`, 484407.14150474017`}, {99.9882`, 
   668500.2152456209`}, {99.9883`, 863304.0960842049`}, {99.9884`, 
   1.0538288292973272`*^6}, {99.9885`, 
   1.223928369892497`*^6}, {99.9886`, 
   1.358151069349844`*^6}, {99.9887`, 
   1.4436018537197143`*^6}, {99.9888`, 
   1.471567167555936`*^6}, {99.9889`, 
   1.4386770107031108`*^6}, {99.989`, 
   1.3474337251571033`*^6}, {99.98910000000001`, 
   1.206018054152098`*^6}, {99.98920000000001`, 
   1.0273789719875318`*^6}, {99.98930000000001`, 
   827711.9871653258`}, {99.9894`, 624517.4470547661`}, {99.9895`, 
   434493.3112763912`}, {99.98960000000001`, 
   271546.2668802631`}, {99.98970000000001`, 
   145195.83424830047`}, {99.9898`, 59597.975846536276`}, {99.9899`, 
   13333.424807004074`}, {99.99000000000001`, 
   1.4778548374239222`}, {99.99010000000001`, 
   9546.365930991567`}, {99.9902`, 30136.213755790428`}, {99.9903`, 
   50329.26450484372`}, {99.99040000000001`, 
   61211.43650049187`}, {99.99050000000001`, 
   58181.79375774372`}, {99.9906`, 42100.992643598314`}, {99.9907`, 
   19598.506481051947`}, {99.99080000000001`, 
   2447.884102815886`}, {99.9909`, 6050.762474493852`}, {99.991`, 
   47201.991349865326`}, {99.9911`, 141421.66859646593`}, {99.9912`, 
   300218.0575426925`}, {99.9913`, 528675.9641149845`}, {99.9914`, 
   823741.4573664954`}, {99.9915`, 1.1734966999925314`*^6}, {99.9916`,
    1.5575965311706052`*^6}, {99.9917`, 
   1.9488858632768858`*^6}, {99.9918`, 
   2.3160542286129966`*^6}, {99.9919`, 
   2.6270326145706433`*^6}, {99.992`, 
   2.852719932349058`*^6}, {99.99210000000001`, 
   2.970559905168779`*^6}, {99.99220000000001`, 
   2.9674852618802455`*^6}, {99.99230000000001`, 
   2.841809004691841`*^6}, {99.9924`, 
   2.6037657460238747`*^6}, {99.9925`, 
   2.2745765447930614`*^6}, {99.99260000000001`, 
   1.8841060333862316`*^6}, {99.99270000000001`, 
   1.4673760546494084`*^6}, {99.9928`, 
   1.060367506635195`*^6}, {99.9929`, 
   695658.25368346`}, {99.99300000000001`, 
   398489.99935574655`}, {99.99310000000001`, 
   183822.56119456282`}, {99.9932`, 54819.36240358618`}, {99.9933`, 
   3026.5354262167316`}, {99.99340000000001`, 
   10280.101486167212`}, {99.99350000000001`, 
   52131.584079556276`}, {99.9936`, 102354.42420546012`}, {99.9937`, 
   137914.54566184452`}, {99.99380000000001`, 
   143685.80534156234`}, {99.9939`, 116183.81624423101`}, {99.994`, 
   65685.81312699754`}, {99.9941`, 16293.259464495655`}, {99.9942`, 
   3757.7396592063697`}, {99.9943`, 71196.78022114829`}, {99.9944`, 
   263136.03241681046`}, {99.9945`, 618585.1966204251`}, {99.9946`, 
   1.1640471696468873`*^6}, {99.9947`, 
   1.9074421621634928`*^6}, {99.9948`, 
   2.833882410239052`*^6}, {99.9949`, 3.90405567313237`*^6}, {99.995`,
    5.055682072659491`*^6}, {99.99510000000001`, 
   6.208131261346862`*^6}, {99.99520000000001`, 
   7.269868799615699`*^6}, {99.99530000000001`, 
   8.1479962141799`*^6}, {99.9954`, 8.758813651212059`*^6}, {99.9955`,
    9.038114802770944`*^6}, {99.99560000000001`, 
   8.949861198259037`*^6}, {99.99570000000001`, 
   8.491995143812856`*^6}, {99.9958`, 
   7.6984334207765255`*^6}, {99.9959`, 
   6.636718223481769`*^6}, {99.99600000000001`, 
   5.401335544570164`*^6}, {99.99610000000001`, 
   4.1032876411022553`*^6}, {99.9962`, 
   2.8570501793411407`*^6}, {99.9963`, 
   1.7664844156866106`*^6}, {99.99640000000001`, 
   911546.0560149102`}, {99.99650000000001`, 
   337687.72504541057`}, {99.9966`, 49662.31616212789`}, {99.9967`, 
   11014.220485333051`}, {99.99680000000001`, 
   149916.70067926153`}, {99.9969`, 371249.42592296394`}, {99.997`, 
   573985.0440702039`}, {99.9971`, 672172.6613239779`}, {99.9972`, 
   617162.7093132898`}, {99.9973`, 418298.5610825093`}, {99.9974`, 
   159190.11126375137`}, {99.9975`, 6889.055099344037`}, {99.9976`, 
   211857.28903701573`}, {99.9977`, 1.097445484728616`*^6}, {99.9978`,
    3.038700743165044`*^6}, {99.9979`, 
   6.431489307696678`*^6}, {99.998`, 
   1.1654127256214151`*^7}, {99.99810000000001`, 
   1.9024725313095316`*^7}, {99.99820000000001`, 
   2.875825988533397`*^7}, {99.99830000000001`, 
   4.092775280583405`*^7}, {99.9984`, 
   5.5433955481785744`*^7}, {99.9985`, 
   7.198736932275228`*^7}, {99.99860000000001`, 
   9.010559231046714`*^7}, {99.99870000000001`, 
   1.0912756879132845`*^8}, {99.9988`, 
   1.2824493566283156`*^8}, {99.9989`, 
   1.4654876982895207`*^8}, {99.99900000000001`, 
   1.630887950398025`*^8}, {99.99910000000001`, 
   1.7694038798517886`*^8}, {99.9992`, 
   1.8727407690049762`*^8}, {99.9993`, 
   1.934212083241554`*^8}, {99.99940000000001`, 
   1.9493079448759955`*^8}, {99.99950000000001`, 
   1.9161105149283525`*^8}, {99.9996`, 
   1.8355199261690336`*^8}, {99.9997`, 
   1.7112742180357695`*^8}, {99.99980000000001`, 
   1.5497651606295362`*^8}, {99.9999`, 
   1.3598374683380157`*^8}, {100.`, 
   1.1509227841822496`*^8}, {100.0001`, 
   9.35316855233305`*^7}, {100.0002`, 
   7.231025004379873`*^7}, {100.0003`, 
   5.256660434840215`*^7}, {100.0004`, 
   3.521381099545413`*^7}, {100.0005`, 
   2.096762182207146`*^7}, {100.0006`, 
   1.0307175273951748`*^7}, {100.0007`, 
   3.443687074219937`*^6}, {100.0008`, 
   319172.0909938909`}, {100.0009`, 624886.4691508369`}, {100.001`, 
   3.839629652685036`*^6}, {100.00110000000001`, 
   9.282792159957027`*^6}, {100.00120000000001`, 
   1.617690363214594`*^7}, {100.00130000000001`, 
   2.371457960763766`*^7}, {100.0014`, 
   3.1123276998223003`*^7}, {100.00150000000001`, 
   3.772278285822957`*^7}, {100.00160000000001`, 
   4.297077901877572`*^7}, {100.00170000000001`, 
   4.649332297408372`*^7}, {100.0018`, 
   4.809858468949901`*^7}, {100.0019`, 
   4.777386804395814`*^7}, {100.00200000000001`, 
   4.566746227227442`*^7}, {100.00210000000001`, 
   4.205818439052258`*^7}, {100.0022`, 
   3.731643524344679`*^7}, {100.0023`, 
   3.186112453043561`*^7}, {100.00240000000001`, 
   2.611684639639511`*^7}, {100.00250000000001`, 
   2.0475351093277786`*^7}, {100.0026`, 
   1.526456928610898`*^7}, {100.0027`, 
   1.0727432825096259`*^7}, {100.00280000000001`, 
   7.01155356380699`*^6}, {100.0029`, 
   4.1696218231500047`*^6}, {100.003`, 
   2.1693002162992805`*^6}, {100.0031`, 
   910514.5775877895`}, {100.0032`, 247468.92969395986`}, {100.0033`, 
   12466.399693349336`}, {100.0034`, 38713.52052913366`}, {100.0035`, 
   179679.7590042069`}, {100.0036`, 323213.6387249924`}, {100.0037`, 
   399394.1422363143`}, {100.0038`, 381919.9691393901`}, {100.0039`, 
   283614.326160101`}, {100.004`, 
   147264.125970723`}, {100.00410000000001`, 
   33457.5539198235`}, {100.00420000000001`, 
   7288.615010277445`}, {100.00430000000001`, 
   125771.23057228878`}, {100.0044`, 
   427548.6798790092`}, {100.00450000000001`, 
   926064.5824913883`}, {100.00460000000001`, 
   1.6068273548210126`*^6}, {100.00470000000001`, 
   2.428830198016985`*^6}, {100.0048`, 
   3.3296556940659885`*^6}, {100.0049`, 
   4.233355835687827`*^6}, {100.00500000000001`, 
   5.059908642966373`*^6}, {100.00510000000001`, 
   5.734928561736933`*^6}, {100.0052`, 
   6.198363502951681`*^6}, {100.0053`, 
   6.411118533755151`*^6}, {100.00540000000001`, 
   6.35887575814467`*^6}, {100.00550000000001`, 
   6.052779744495396`*^6}, {100.0056`, 
   5.527073307789168`*^6}, {100.0057`, 
   4.834148684727312`*^6}, {100.00580000000001`, 
   4.037775067693357`*^6}, {100.0059`, 
   3.2054465135499393`*^6}, {100.006`, 
   2.400845094917662`*^6}, {100.0061`, 
   1.6773369586025865`*^6}, {100.0062`, 
   1.0732294466178913`*^6}, {100.0063`, 
   609246.9462916934`}, {100.0064`, 288371.9280090763`}, {100.0065`, 
   97885.98961812796`}, {100.0066`, 13175.954352500674`}, {100.0067`, 
   2671.8581152992074`}, {100.0068`, 33180.8081956854`}, {100.0069`, 
   74879.15044292489`}, {100.007`, 
   105320.26006151935`}, {100.00710000000001`, 
   111989.1796066404`}, {100.00720000000001`, 
   93159.75531063265`}, {100.00730000000001`, 
   57054.633435510834`}, {100.0074`, 
   19538.03841524044`}, {100.00750000000001`, 
   758.3242056625403`}, {100.00760000000001`, 
   21277.671150084952`}, {100.00770000000001`, 
   98268.79276605384`}, {100.0078`, 242320.59325159696`}, {100.0079`, 
   455285.73967379465`}, {100.00800000000001`, 
   729441.1594492072`}, {100.00810000000001`, 
   1.0480410677191823`*^6}, {100.0082`, 
   1.3871489717460165`*^6}, {100.0083`, 
   1.7184649917589629`*^6}, {100.00840000000001`, 
   2.012740522166382`*^6}, {100.00850000000001`, 
   2.2433073813179927`*^6}, {100.0086`, 
   2.3892498069632286`*^6}, {100.0087`, 
   2.437811768754389`*^6}, {100.00880000000001`, 
   2.385747887226385`*^6}, {100.0089`, 
   2.239476243883074`*^6}, {100.009`, 
   2.0140542725085174`*^6}, {100.0091`, 
   1.7311522326453237`*^6}, {100.0092`, 
   1.4163228918969373`*^6}, {100.0093`, 
   1.095945353432984`*^6}, {100.0094`, 
   794247.1192294351`}, {100.0095`, 530779.7536792547`}, {100.0096`, 
   318646.5975802199`}, {100.0097`, 163667.62190115865`}, {100.0098`, 
   64533.7233387026`}, {100.0099`, 13868.84376476787`}, {100.01`, 
   1.4778114216281888`}}]
```

I can interpolate the data with

```
Clear[Interpolate]
Interpolate[100] = Interpolation[data4[100], InterpolationOrder -> 2];
```

However, I noticed that `Interpolation[]` gives negative values in a small domain of my interpolation:

```
Plot[Interpolate[100][x], {x, 99.98, 100.01}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Interpolate[100][x], {x, 100.0033, 100.0034}, 
 PlotRange -> {-2*10^4, 0}]
```

[image]

Why is `Interpolation[]` giving a negative value when none of the data gives negative values? I had looked at [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92580/how-to-avoid-creating-negative-values-when-using-interpolation), which suggested adding `InterpolationOrder`, but unfortunately this solution had no effect.

Comment: Interpolation is in general not monotonic. There can be overshoot (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge's_phenomenon). You can enforce monotonicity by using 1st order interpolation, or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation.  As a side note, `Interpolate` is a very bad name for a variable!

Comment: Strongly related: "[Monotone, periodic 1d-interpolation with continuous 1st order derivative](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14662/280)."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One good way to interpolate a function of this nature is to take its `Log`, interpolate, and take `Exp` of the result.

```
lntrp = Interpolation[data4[100] /. {x_, y_} -> {x, Log[y]}]
Plot[Exp[lntrp[x]], {x, 99.98, 100.01}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment to John Doty's answer:

While the answer might suit your needs (i.e. a smooth curve that passes through your points and remains positive), I would not say that it is a good way of interpolating.

In the example below, I illustrate two bad properties of taking the exponential of log-interpolated values:

- sensitivity to vertical translation (the interpolation is sensitive to a vertical translation)
- sensitivity to small absolute variations  near 0

Naturally, these two "properties" are related.

```
 data1 = {{0, 1}, {1, 10^-3}, {2, 1}};
 data2 = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}} /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y + 1};
 data3 = {{0, 1}, {1, 10^-5}, {2, 1}};
```

One would expect interpolation of these three datasets to have quasi-exact same shapes. It is the case with "classic" interpolation:

```
int1 = Interpolation[data1, InterpolationOrder -> 2];
int2 = Interpolation[data2, InterpolationOrder -> 2];
int3 = Interpolation[data3, InterpolationOrder -> 2];
Plot[{int1[t], int2[t] - 1, int3[t]}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

But not at all with the "Log-Exp trick":

```
int4 = Interpolation[data1 /. {x_, y_} -> {x, Log[y]}, InterpolationOrder -> 2];
int5 = Interpolation[data2 /. {x_, y_} -> {x, Log[y]}, InterpolationOrder -> 2];
int6 = Interpolation[data3 /. {x_, y_} -> {x, Log[y]}, InterpolationOrder -> 2];
Plot[{Exp@int4[t], -1 + Exp@int5[t], Exp@int6[t]}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

So maybe it is good enough for you in this case, but I would not recommend it generally speaking (and I would interrogate myself on the grounds to create an interpolation method that works only on a limited domain - positive values).

Comment: However, the `Log-Exp` pair can be replaced with any other functional pair such that $f(g(x))=x$ and $f(x)>0$ for domain of interest. For instance `g[x]=Sqrt[x]` and `f[x]=x^2`.

Comment: @yarchik Of course, but with the same drawback more or less amplified (based on the slope of $g$). Bottom line: what is the missing information that is sought between the known points? If the purpose of interpolating is to take the derivative, that could be a very bad strategy.

Comment: The problem is intrinsically unsymmetrical: zero is a line that must not be crossed, but there is no upper limit. Looking at the function, the peaks are rounded, but the valleys are nearly flat. The `Log` method reflects this, while you seem to insist that a proper method should not.

Answer (score 1):

Linear interpolation doesn't show this over/under-swinging behavior of polynomial interpolation of higher order.

```
Clear[Interpolate]
Interpolate[100] = Interpolation[data4[100], InterpolationOrder -> 1];


Plot[Interpolate[100][x], {x, 100.0033, 100.0034}, PlotRange -> {-2*10^4, +10*10^4}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you don't want to use linear interpolation you can use Akima Interpolation which gives very smooth results with little over/undershooting.

```
f = ResourceFunction["AkimaInterpolation"][data4[100]];
Plot[f[x], {x, 99.98, 100.01}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Interpolate[100][x], {x, 100.0033, 100.0034},  PlotRange -> {-2*10^4, +10*10^4}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for `AkimaInterpolation` - I saw the author of that function give a talk on it a couple of days ago.  Much more satisfying than the accepted answer.