# Take part from plot

Tags: plotting

I want to get the line from plot.
Then I use

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 1][[1, 1, 1, 3]]
```

I get somthing.
But when I use

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 1][[1, 1, 1, 3, 2]]
```

I get

```
"Charting`Private`Tag$33789#1"
```

And I find the solution from here.

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114775

My question is : why can't that work?

Comment: That solution using `[[1, 1, 1, 3]]` is really not recommended, because the details of how the `Graphics[]` primitives are embedded can differ between versions of *Mathematica*. Try `Cases[Normal[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 1]], _Line, Infinity]` instead.

Comment: ok,thanks. I use `pl = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 1];
Graphics@Line@Cases[pl, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity]` to solve it.

Comment: Your proposal removes the `Line[]` head only to add it back in later. Don't you think this is a little wasteful?