# Interpolation of unevenly spaced data, is it possible?

Tags: interpolation

I need to interpolate data, that consists of many points in the beginning and a few in the end of the interval, like in the following example:

```
(* Generate data *)
dat = {#, Exp[-#]} & /@ Append[Range[0, 3, .5], 10];

(* Make interpolations of different orders *)
int = Interpolation[dat, InterpolationOrder -> #] & /@ Range[2, 7];

Show[
 ListPlot[dat, PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1}], 
 Plot[Evaluate@Through@int[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
]
```

But this produces quite poor results:

[image]

Is it possible somehow to produce more appropriate result?

Comment: You might want to look up monotonic interpolation; there have been a few answers on this site using it.

Comment: Why not stick with linear interpolation (InterpolationOrder->1) in the absence of more information? Or you can move to log-space.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, but what I've found so far doesn't solve this type of problems

Comment: What do you actually need the interpolation function for? You might get better results with a NLM

Comment: @MarkusRoellig It seems log-space is not very useful when one deals with data, containing almost constant intervals. I don't use Interpolation order 1, because I still want is to visualize the curvature, but not just straight lines.

Comment: Have you tried, for instance, the second solution in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14040)?

Comment: for this toy example a fit to `Exp` will obviously work pretty well. What are you actually trying to acomplish?

Comment: This blog post discusses a similar problem ["Find Fit for Non-linear data"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2014/04/19/find-fit-for-non-linear-data/).

Comment: Method -> "Spline" with InterpolationOrder -> 2 usually works better than the default in such cases (can't test right now: writing from a smartphone).

Answer (score 5):

`Interpolation` sometimes does not handle endpoints well, and this appears to be exacerbated in the present case, because the upper endpoint is far removed from the rest of the points.  One workaround is to provide more, but very closely spaced, points of identical value (so that there is no need to know the form of the original function there) near the upper end of the data.

```
{#, Exp[-#]} & /@ Append[Range[0, 3, .5], 10];
dat = Join[%, Array[(Last@% + {0.01 #, 0}) &, 4]]; 
int = Interpolation[dat, InterpolationOrder -> #] & /@ Range[2, 7]; 
Show[ListPlot[dat, PlotRange -> {All, {-1.1, 1.1}}], 
     Plot[Evaluate@Through@int[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

In effect, this causes higher derivatives of the interpolation function to be very small at the upper end of the interval.

Comment: What do you do when you know only the points and not the function?

Comment: @rewi  Good question.  I have modified my answer to use additional points that do not rely on knowing the original function.  Not surprisingly, there is no change in the resulting curve.

Answer (score 3):

One could try to find a solution with `FindFormula`.

```
dat = {#, Exp[-#]} & /@ Append[Range[0, 3, .5], 10];
Plot[Evaluate@FindFormula[dat, x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize@Medium, Point@dat}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

For the 2nd try to solve the problem I use `BSplines`. I insert a point until the curve is smooth. **We don't know the function!**

```
Manipulate[
 data = {{0, 1}, {0.5, 0.606531}, {1, 0.367879}, {1.5, 0.22313}, {2, .135335}, {2.5, 0.082085}, {3, 0.0497871}, {a, b}, {10, 0.0000453999}};
 spline = BSplineFunction@data;
 p = ParametricPlot[spline[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
   AspectRatio -> 0.5, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize@Medium, Point@data}],
 {a, 3, 10}, {b, 0.0497871, 0.0000453999}]
```

[image]

Now I build the Interpolation and compare the solution with the 1st solution:

```
f = Interpolation@Cases[p, Line[_], \[Infinity]][[1, 1]];

dat = {#, Exp[-#]} & /@ Append[Range[0, 3, .5], 10];
Show[
 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All,  PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize@Medium, Point@dat}], 
 Plot[Evaluate@FindFormula[dat, x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in a comment this blog post, ["Find Fit for Non-linear data"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2014/04/19/find-fit-for-non-linear-data/), discusses a similar problem.

[Quantile Regression](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/quantile-regression-with-b-splines/) (QR) can produce a good enough interpolation of order two:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/QuantileRegression.m"]

qfunc = First@
   QuantileRegression[dat, dat[[All, 1]], {0.5}, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 2];

Show[Plot[qfunc[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All], 
 ListPlot[dat, PlotRange -> {All, {-1.1, 1.1}}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

I said "interpolation" (not "fitting") because the data x-coordinates are given to be the knots for the basis functions in `QuantileRegression`. This kind of QR interpolation is very similar to using `Method -> "Spline"` with `InterpolationOrder -> 2` as mentioned in a comment by Alexey Popkov.

What I find kind of interesting is that increasing the order of interpolation makes oscillations on the opposite end of the plot in the question:

```
qfuncs = Table[
   First@QuantileRegression[dat, dat[[All, 1]], {0.5}, 
     InterpolationOrder -> i], {i, 2, 7}];

Show[Plot[Evaluate@Through@qfuncs[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> Range[2, 7]], 
 ListPlot[dat, PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you see a way to get QuantileRegression working for extremely unevenly spaced datasets (my example: https://pastebin.com/SCFyCA24)? I want to find a fit and some sort of confidence intervals, from which I can extract the values for the periods that were not sampled - so your QuantileRegression would be perfect - but it seems to have problems with such datasets...

Comment: Yes you can use QuantileRegression.m -- just rescale the data before the QR calculations. See [this screenshot](http://imgur.com/bwQVyxS.png).

Comment: Thanks - rescaling does the trick!

Comment: I'm really like your QuantileRegression package, it helped me in many cases! However, I recently ran into problems with larger datasets (e.g. https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zvye4c3jblxgyo/testdata.csv?dl=0), where rescaling doesn't help either. The kernel is eating up all the memory and crashes after some point. It might be a problem with the new Mathematica V11.1 or V11.1.1, because the QuantileRegression worked fine for this dataset earlier... Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: @mjayvizzle I made a few experiments with the data you linked... I don't know what are your end goals, but the following suggestions might help. **1)** Use the option `Method -> {LinearProgramming, Method -> "CLP"}`. **2)** Use a 10-20% sample of the data. See [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/7CCtTkF.png).

Comment: Thanks, it works with 10-20% of the data, so I guess this is the best option at the moment. I still think there's a problem with the LinearProgramming in V11.1 or V11.1.1, because it runs fine with all the data in earlier versions...we'll see if this gets fixed!

Comment: @mjayvizzle I assume there are some changes in the optimization algorithms (`LinearProgramming` more precisely.) If you feel like it -- sorry, I am delegating -- (i) you can try to find a minimal dataset showing the issue and send a bug report to WRI, and/or (ii) open a new question here at MSE.

Answer (score 2):

In such situations some sort of preprocessing of the data might be very useful:

```
Clear[int, x]
int[x_] = 
  With[{data = {#1, Log@#2} & @@@ dat}, 
     Exp[Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> #, 
        Method -> "Spline"][x]]] & /@ Range[2, 7];

Show[Plot[Evaluate@int[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All], 
 ListPlot[dat], PlotRange -> {0, 1.}]
```

[image: plot]

Of course here the use of Log for preprocessing was cheating, but the idea is clear: in general one should guess the appropriate function.