# A problem when interpolating the data

Tags: interpolation

I have some data in a form `data = {{x,y,f[x,y]},...}`, where `f[x,y]` takes only positive values. When I try to interpolate it, `Interpolation[data]`, interpolated function has negative values at particular points, like on the plot. Is there some way to interpolate the data with forced condition to take only positive values (not involved `InterpolationOrder->0`)?

[image]

Comment: You could try using a monotonic interpolation method (e.g. [Steffen](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14040)) to compute the gradients in one direction.

Comment: You could take the log of the data, interpolate and then exponentiate.  This is guaranteed to be positive, but you will have to judge the fit for yourself.