# Approximately Fit Data Without FindFit

Tags: interpolation, data

I have some noisy data, and I'd like to analyze the derivative of the function the data approximately matches. `Interpolation` is normally great, but doesn't work very well at all here.

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[x] + RandomReal[{-.15, .15}]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], .05}];
```

[image: Almost sin(x)]

```
xi = Interpolation[data];
Plot[xi'[t], {t, 0, 6.25}];
```

[image: Not cos(x)]

As you can see, the derivative (as expected when you think of how interpolation works) is not at all `Cos[x]`. In this case, because it is so obvious that the curve is of the `Sin[x]` family, it would be trivial to fit it and take the derivative of the fit. In the data I actually collected, I do not know the function, and assuming some high-order polynomial, while it may fit well, is almost certainly an incorrect assumption.

Is there a way to plot the derivative cleanly without requiring other knowledge about the function? Is it possible to tell `Interpolation` that it doesn't need to hit every point exactly?

Comment: This also looks like a question that a Laguerre filter could help.  Based on Laguerre polynomials they need fewer inputs than a moving average and employ a feedback technique.  I'll look around and see if I have an old Mma implmentation.

Comment: You might want to look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10997/1089

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**

Since Version 12, Mathematica now incorporates a range of (underrated IMHO) [regularisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_deconvolution) methods to `Fit` and `FindFit`.

---

As explained in this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10997/1089), you can do a non-parametric fit to your data using B-Splines, and differentiate this fit:

```
pts = Table[{x, Sin[2 Pi x] + RandomReal[{-.15, .15}]}, {x, 0, 
    1, .0125}];

kfun[n_, d_] := 
  Join[ConstantArray[0, d], Range[0, 1, 1/(n - d)], 
   ConstantArray[1, d]]; 
uparam[pts_] := N[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[pts] - 1)]];
mbasis[pts_, n_, d_] := 
  With[{param = uparam[pts]}, 
   Table[BSplineBasis[{d, kfun[n, d]}, j - 1, param[[i]]], {i, 
     Length[param]}, {j, n}]];

Clear[ctrlpts];
ctrlpts[lambda_: 0] := 
  With[{mat = mbasis[pts, 25, 3], 
    reg = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 
        2., {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1 -> -1.}, {25, 25}, 0.]}, 
   LinearSolve[Transpose[mat].mat + 10^(lambda) Transpose[reg].reg, 
    Transpose[mat].(Last /@ pts)]];

Show[ListPlot[pts, AxesLabel -> {x, y}], 
 ListLinePlot[{First /@ pts, mbasis[pts, 25, 3].ctrlpts[0.25]} // 
   Transpose, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that the fit does not go through all the points as you requested.
Here we consider an [explicit penalty function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization). The idea here is that
we  find the best (spline) weights  subject to a prior corresponding to a roughness penalty (which allows us to tune how smooth the spine function should be, which involves adding a tunable cost to unsmooth spline).

The fit is now
 controlled by the relative weight of the penalty (given as an argument to
ctrlpts).  We can differentiate it:

```
df[x_] = BSplineFunction[ctrlpts[1], SplineDegree -> 3]'[x];
Plot[{df[x], 2 Pi Cos[2 Pi x]}, {x, 0.05, 0.95}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are known methods (such as [cross validation](http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~wahba/ftp1/oldie/golub.heath.wahba.pdf)) to estimate automatically what the proper amount of smoothing should be, depending on
what it is you want to estimate (the function, its derivative, its second derivative etc.).

Note that the behaviour of your basis function at the edge of the requested interval needs to be addressed depending on  what a proper boundary should be.
For instance, the Fourier filtering method presented by others is formally 
equivalent to this B-Sline fit, while assuming periodic boundary condition 
and a particular choice of [Wiener filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_deconvolution).

Comment: Very nice! Can you explain what you mean by "the relative weight of the penalty"?

Comment: In the expression `LinearSolve[Transpose[mat].mat +10^(lambda) Transpose[reg].reg,Transpose[mat].(Last /@ pts)]`, `10^lambda` weights the penalty (or regularisation) relative to the goodness of fit term (`Transpose[mat].mat`).

Answer (score 11):

You want to remove high-frequency noise while retaining the low-frequency signal. This is a job for a bandpass filter. A simple one is the `MovingAverage`, which you can apply like so:

```
xsi = Interpolation[MovingAverage[data, 20]]
Plot[{Derivative[1][xsi][t], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 6.25},  PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1}]
```

[image: derivative with moving average]

Comment: You can knock down almost all the noise using `xbi=Interpolation[Transpose[{data[[All,1]],LowpassFilter[data[[All,2]],8,Length[data],TukeyWindow,SampleRate->Floor[Pi/0.05],Padding->"Periodic"]}]]`.

Comment: Your comment works better than your answer - why not to put it in the answer with plots? ;)

Comment: Well, the comment version is a lot more fiddly; look at all the magic numbers I had to put in it. Also, bandpass filters are only natively in v9, which I assume not everybody has yet.

Comment: I'm on v7 with access to v8, so no `LowpassFilter`. My original idea was actually something similar to `MovingAverage`. Unfortunately the Mathematica implementation of `MovingAverage` clobbers a value (maybe more than one?) each time. I ported the Matlab version of moving average and Nested it around 10 times with a window of 5. I wasn't happy with this solution, which is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 5):

As Xerxes rightfully says `LowPassFilter` would be a good one if you have v9. A poor man's filter would be the following:

```
With[{x = data\[Transpose][[1]], y = data\[Transpose][[2]], ld = Length@data},
 Table[
  ListPlot[
   Chop[
    InverseFourier[(Boole[Abs[# - Round[(ld + 1)/2]] > num] & /@ Range[ld]) Fourier[y]]
    ]
   ], {num, 10, 60, 10}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It works by performing a DFT, multiplying the highest frequency components with 0, and doing an inverse DFT.

Alternatively, `ListConvolve` could be used:

```
Transpose[{
  data\[Transpose][[1]], 
  ListConvolve[{1, 1, 2, 1, 1}/6, data\[Transpose][[2]], {3, 3}]}
] // ListPlot
```

You could play with various kernels to see how it suits your data.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Clever idea! Unfortunately when I tried plotting the derivative of the interpolation function of the filtered data, it was a total mess. It oscillated like crazy.