# How to do Independent Component Analysis?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, data, machine-learning

The new experimental function in 10.3.1 [`DimensionReduce[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DimensionReduce.html), has the following three options for `Method`:

- `"PrincipalComponentsAnalysis"`
- `"LatentSemanticAnalysis"`
- `"LowRankMatrixFactorization"`

What about Independent Component Analysis (ICA) - is that already implemented somewhere, or am I missing it?

Comment: I believe it is not implemented.

Comment: If it is not currently available, there are at least two packages in *R* for ICA which can be accessed from *Mathematica*.

Comment: You could easily link to the [*FastICA* algorithm](http://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/fastica/) with either [`RLink`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/guide/RLink.html) or [`MATLink`](http://matlink.org/).

Comment: It seems to me that the question and accepted answer of [Disentangling the data](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47136/disentangling-the-data) are related. To be clear, Non-Negative Matrix Factorization (NNMF) does dimension reduction, but its norm minimization process does not enforce variable independence. (It enforces non-negativity.)

Comment: I think it is a good idea to add to the question an example of data for which ICA would give results that help interpreting it. E.g. the ["cocktail party problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_party_effect).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that Non-Negative Matrix Factorization (NNMF) can be applied for doing ICA. At least in some cases.

In order to demonstrate this I will make up some data in the spirit of the ["cocktail party problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_party_effect). Then I am going to apply an NNMF algorithm.

To be clear, NNMF does dimension reduction, but its norm minimization process does not enforce variable independence. (It enforces non-negativity.) There are at least several articles discussing modification of NNMF to do ICA. For example this one: ["A new nonnegative matrix factorization for independent component analysis"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224149642_A_new_nonnegative_matrix_factorization_for_independent_component_analysis). (From it I took the data generation formulas.)

**Data**

```
(*Signal functions*)
Clear[s1, s2, s3]
s1[t_] := Sin[600 \[Pi] t/10000 + 6*Cos[120 \[Pi] t/10000]] + 1.2
s2[t_] := Sin[\[Pi] t/10] + 1.2
s3[t_?NumericQ] := (((QuotientRemainder[t, 23][[2]] - 11)/9)^5 + 2.8)/2 + 0.2

(*Mixing matrix*)
A = {{0.44, 0.2, 0.31}, {0.45, 0.8, 0.23}, {0.12, 0.32, 0.71}};

(*Signals matrix*)
nSize = 600;
S = Table[{s1[t], s2[t], s3[t]}, {t, 0, nSize, 0.5}];

(*Mixed signals matrix*)
M = A.Transpose[S];

(*Signals*)
Grid[{Map[
   Plot[#, {t, 0, nSize}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
     ImageSize -> 250] &, {s1[t], s2[t], s3[t]}]}]
```

[image]

```
(*Mixed signals*)
Grid[{Map[ListLinePlot[#, ImageSize -> 250] &, M]}]
```

[image]

**Application of Non-Negative Matrix Factorization (NNMF)**

Load NNMF package (from [MathematicaForPrediction at GitHub](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction)):

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/NonNegativeMatrixFactorization.m"]
```

After several applications of NNMF we get signals close to the originals:

```
{W, H} = GDCLS[M, 3];
Grid[{Map[ListLinePlot[#, ImageSize -> 250] &, Normal[H]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The package [IndependentComponentAnalysis.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/IndependentComponentAnalysis.m) can be used for Independent Component Analysis (ICA).

This answer uses the generated data from [my previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/106102/34008) (which is about opportunistic application of general Non-Negative Matrix Factorization for ICA).

Load the package:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/IndependentComponentAnalysis.m"]
```

It is important to note that the usual ICA model interpretation for the factorized matrix $X$ is that each column is a variable (audio signal) and each row is an observation (recordings of the microphones at a given time). The matrix $M \in R^{3 \times 1201}$ was constructed with the interpretation that each row is a signal, hence we have to transpose $M$ in order to apply the ICA algorithms, $X=M^T$.

```
X = Transpose[M];

{S, A} = IndependentComponentAnalysis[X, 3];
```

Check the approximation of the obtained factorization:

```
Norm[X - S.A]    
(* 3.10715*10^-14 *)
```

Plot the found source signals:

```
Grid[{Map[ListLinePlot[#, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 250] &, 
   Transpose[S]]}]
```

[image]

Because of the random initialization of the inverting matrix in the algorithm the result my vary. Here is the plot from another run:

[image]

The package also provides the function `FastICA` that returns an association with elements that correspond to the result of the function `fastICA` provided by the R package "fastICA". See

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fastICA/index.html
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fastICA/fastICA.pdf

Here is an example usage:

```
res = FastICA[X, 3];

Keys[res]    
(* {"X", "K", "W", "A", "S"} *)

Grid[{Map[
   ListLinePlot[#, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Medium] &, 
   Transpose[res["S"]]]}]
```

[image]

Note that (in adherence to the cited documents) the function `FastICA` returns the matrices S and A for the centralized matrix X. This means, for example, that in order to check the approximation proper mean has to be supplied:

```
Norm[X - Map[# + Mean[X] &, res["S"].res["A"]]]
(* 2.56719*10^-14 *)
```

### Further readings

1. More explanations and references are given in the blog post ["Independent component analysis for multidimensional signals"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2016/05/23/independent-component-analysis-for-multidimensional-signals/). For example:

   - the section ["ICA for mixed time series of city temperatures"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2016/05/23/independent-component-analysis-for-multidimensional-signals/#ica-for-mixed-time-series-of-city-temperatures),
   - the section ["Signatures and results"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2016/05/23/independent-component-analysis-for-multidimensional-signals/#signatures-and-results).
2. The blog post ["Comparison of PCA, NNMF, and ICA over image de-noising"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2016/05/26/comparison-of-pca-nnmf-and-ica-over-image-de-noising/) has applications to image processing.

[image: Image collage of orginal, noised, PCA, NNMF, ICA de-noised 6 and 7 images]