# Code that generates a mandala

Tags: graphics, programming, generative-art

My little brother asked me to print original mandalas for coloring. I would like some idea on how to create them, but without color, so he can color them.

examples

[image]
[image]

Comment: It would be better to do this in Adobe Illustrator. Illustrator has a function called "Array" that lets you arrange patterns around the perimeter of a circle. You first drawn your tile as a wedge, then make an array around the circle. If you can define your tile in Mathematica, then you can do the same thing in Mathematica by using the **CirclePoints** function. This will give you the coordinates of where to plot your tiles. Another function to look at is **SectorChart**. In Mathematica, it will be a more involved process than Illustrator.

Comment: People, there is no good reason to close this question as too broad. It has multiple up-voted answers. How can it be too broad?

Comment: related: [How to generate a random snowflake](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39361/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for linking the snowflake making. I was wondering where to find similar work -- I was sure there are similar things already done in the Mathematica community.

Answer (score 105):

Here is one way to come up with "mandalas" -- we generate a segment and then by appropriate number of rotations we produce a "mandala".

Here is an example function of a random seed segment generation:

```
Clear[MakeSeedSegment]
MakeSeedSegment[radius_, angle_, n_Integer: 10, connectingFunc_: Polygon, keepGridPoints_: False] :=
  Block[{t},
   t = Table[
     Line[{radius*r*{Cos[angle], Sin[angle]}, {radius*r, 0}}], {r, 0, 1, 1/n}];
   Join[If[TrueQ[keepGridPoints], t, {}], {GrayLevel[0.25], 
     connectingFunc@
      RandomSample[Flatten[t /. Line[{x_, y_}] :> {x, y}, 1]]}]
   ];

seed = MakeSeedSegment[10, \[Pi]/12, 10];
Graphics[seed, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

This function makes symmetric a given seed segment:

```
Clear[MakeSymmetric]
MakeSymmetric[seed_] := {seed, 
   GeometricTransformation[seed, ReflectionTransform[{0, 1}]]};

seed = MakeSymmetric[seed];
Graphics[seed, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Using a seed segment we can generate mandalas with different specification signatures:

```
Clear[MakeMandala]
MakeMandala[opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=     
  MakeMandala[
   MakeSymmetric[
    MakeSeedSegment[20, \[Pi]/12, 12, 
     RandomChoice[{Line, Polygon, BezierCurve, 
       FilledCurve[BezierCurve[#]] &}], False]], \[Pi]/6, opts];
MakeMandala[seed_, angle_?NumericQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Graphics[GeometricTransformation[seed, 
    Table[RotationMatrix[a], {a, 0, 2 \[Pi] - angle, angle}]], opts];
```

This code randomly selects symmetricity and seed generation parameters (number of concentric circles, angles, connecting function):

```
n = 12;
Multicolumn@
 MapThread[
  If[#1,
    MakeMandala[MakeSeedSegment[10, #2, #3], #2],
    MakeMandala[MakeSymmetric[MakeSeedSegment[10, #2, #3, #4, False]],
      2 #2]
    ] &, {RandomChoice[{False, True}, n], 
   RandomChoice[{\[Pi]/7, \[Pi]/8, \[Pi]/6}, n], 
   RandomInteger[{8, 14}, n], 
   RandomChoice[{Line, Polygon, BezierCurve, FilledCurve[BezierCurve[#]] &}, n]}]
```

[image]

Here is a more concise way to generate symmetric segment mandalas:

```
Multicolumn[Table[MakeMandala[], {30}], 5]
```

[image]

### Going further

At this point we can consider blending and/or coloring of generated mandalas.

One way to do mandalas blending is to convert a set of mandala graphics into images and do weighted blending of small image samples.

Using this approach I got better looking results using only `Polygon` and `FilledCurve[BezierCurve[#]] &` in `MakeSeedSegment`.

```
iSize = 400;

AbsoluteTiming[
 mandalaImages = 
   Table[Image[
     MakeMandala[
      MakeSymmetric@
       MakeSeedSegment[10, \[Pi]/12, 12, 
        RandomChoice[{Polygon, 
          FilledCurve[BezierCurve[#]] &}]], \[Pi]/6], 
     ImageSize -> {iSize, iSize}, ColorSpace -> "Grayscale"], {200}];
 ]

(* {20.5542, Null}

Multicolumn[Table[
  RemoveBackground@
   ImageAdjust[
    Blend[Colorize[#, 
        ColorFunction -> 
         RandomChoice[{"BrightBands", "IslandColors", 
           "FruitPunchColors", "AvocadoColors", "Rainbow"}]] & /@ 
      RandomChoice[mandalaImages, 4], RandomReal[1, 4]]], {30}], 5]
```

[image]

### Album

See [this album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdm5R.jpg) with generated mandalas at different stages of the working on this question/answer.

Comment: "The procedure, though, comes from a machine learning algorithm for generating mandalas, which I will describe in a different answer." - Looking forward to...

Comment: @ercegovac Thanks -- I will describe the procedure in the next few days.

Comment: This reminds me of how Mathematica was used to create 'alien' symbols for the movie Arrival. In any case, your results should probably go into a hall of fame of Mathematica denomstrations

Comment: @YuriyS Thank you for your kind words. I consider starting a more elaborated discussion on this in Community.

Comment: Anton, Only thing missing from this post are the nunchaku. :-) Gets the *favourite* from me.

Comment: @Edmund :) You mean like [Lissajous-do](http://nunchaku.wikia.com/wiki/Lissajous-do)? ([Demo movie here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRyKsvYYhok). )

Comment: @ercegovac Please see [my new answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137519/34008) describing the use of dimension reduction algorithms to generate mandalas.

Answer (score 68):

For this one I've defined three types of layer, a flower, a simple circle and a ring of small circles. You could add more for greater variety.

```
flower[n_, a_, r_] := Module[{b = RandomChoice[{-1/(2 n), 0}]},
  Cases[ParametricPlot[
   r (a + Cos[n t])/(a + 1) {Cos[t + b Sin[2 n t]], Sin[t + b Sin[2 n t]]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}],
   l_Line :> FilledCurve[l], -1]]

disk[_, _, r_] := Disk[{0, 0}, r]

spots[n_, a_, r_] := Translate[Disk[{0, 0}, r a/(4 n)], r CirclePoints[n]]

mandala[n_, m_] := Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], White, Table[
    RandomChoice[{3, 2, 1} -> {flower, disk, spots}][n, 
      RandomReal[{3, 5}], i]~Rotate~(Pi i/n), {i, m, 1, -1}]}, 
  PlotRange -> All]

GraphicsGrid[Table[mandala[16, 20], {2}, {2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Much more faithful to the typical mandala look than the ones in my answer. (+1 of course.)

Comment: Interestingly, the [colored versions](http://i.imgur.com/BZgMbaz.png) of mandalas made with this algorithm make me think more of Viking or Native American art.

Comment: The challenge now is to get it down to 140 characters for WTC 2017 TAP.

Answer (score 30):

The point of using machine learning algorithms for generation of mandala images mentioned in the comments of [my previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136986/34008) is clarified in this blog post:

- ["Comparison of dimension reduction algorithms over mandala images generation"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2017/02/10/comparison-of-dimension-reduction-algorithms-over-mandala-images-generation/) (WordPress),
  ([GitHub link](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/MarkdownDocuments/Comparison-of-dimension-reduction-algorithms-over-mandala-images-generation.md)), 
  ([Community link](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1011591))

The article shows that with Non-Negative Matrix Factorization (NNMF) we can use mandalas made with [the seed segment rotation algorithm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136986/34008) to extract layer types and superimpose them to make [colored mandalas](https://i.imgur.com/gPcN1WY.png). Using the same approach with Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) or [Independent Component Analysis (ICA)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115740)  does not produce good layers and the superimposition produces [more "watered-down", less diverse mandalas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXjfr.jpg).

Here are the bases produced with SVD, ICA, and NNMF:

[image]

Note the different look of the NNMF basis compared those of SVD and ICA.

Here are colored mandalas produced with NNMF:

[image]

Answer (score 29):

Completeley trial & error, but you can play around with it to your heart's content:

```
a = DeleteDuplicates[RotationMatrix[ # Pi/5].{Cos[Log@t] + t Sin[t], 
   Sin[Log@t] - t Cos[t] + 12} & /@ Range@12];
b = DeleteDuplicates[RotationMatrix[ # Pi/5].(2 {Cos[2 t], Sin[2 t] + 24}) & /@ 
Range@12];
c = DeleteDuplicates[RotationMatrix[ # Pi/5].(2 {Cos[2 t], Sin[2 t] + 2}) & /@ Range@12];
d = DeleteDuplicates[RotationMatrix[ # Pi/5].(.5 {Cos[2 t], Sin[2 t] + 48}) & /@ 
Range@12];
Quiet@Show[
    With[{x = 
   ParametricPlot[a, {t, .0001, Sqrt@Pi*Pi}, 
    PlotRange -> ({{-#, #}, {-#, #}} &@#), Ticks -> None, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}, 
    Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 1000]}, x], 
With[{x = 
    ParametricPlot[2 a, {t, .0001, Sqrt@Pi*Pi}, 
    PlotRange -> ({{-#, #}, {-#, #}} & #), Ticks -> None, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}, 
    Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 1000]}, x],
With[{x = 
    ParametricPlot[4 a, {t, .0001, Sqrt@Pi*Pi}, 
    PlotRange -> ({{-#, #}, {-#, #}} & #), Ticks -> None, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}, 
    Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 1000]}, x],
With[{x = 
    ParametricPlot[(# {Cos[2 t], Sin[2 t]} & /@ {9, 19, 36, 38, 68, 70}), 
    {t, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> ({{-#, #}, {-#, #}} &@#), 
    Ticks -> None, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}, Axes -> False, 
    PlotPoints -> 1000]}, x],
With[{x = 
    ParametricPlot[b, {t, 0, Pi}, 
    PlotRange -> ({{-#, #}, {-#, #}} &@#), Ticks -> None, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}, 
    Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 1000]}, x],
With[{x = 
    ParametricPlot[c, {t, 0, Pi}, 
    PlotRange -> ({{-#, #}, {-#, #}} &@#), Ticks -> None, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}, 
    Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 1000]}, x],
With[{x = 
    ParametricPlot[d, {t, 0, Pi}, 
    PlotRange -> ({{-#, #}, {-#, #}} &@#), Ticks -> None, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}, 
    Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 1000]}, x]

] &@80
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

The presentation of Chris Carlson (from WRI) at WTC-2016 discusses design spaces and the examples he gave are very relevant to this discussion.

- Chris Carlson, ["Social Exploration of Design Spaces: A Proposal"](http://wac.36f4.edgecastcdn.net/0036F4/pub/www.wolfram.com/technology-conference/2016/SocialExplorationOfDesignSpaces.nb), (2016), Wolfram Technology Conference 2016. (link to notebook).
- [The presentation movie at YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YK2523nfcms).

If you download the presentation notebook you use the dynamic interface code to generate mandalas. Below are some examples.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 12):

Recently the function 
[`RandomMandala`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RandomMandala)
was added to the 
[Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/).

---

Here are multi-mandala mode examples run in a notebook with "ReverseColor" stylesheet:

```
SeedRandom[5798]
Multicolumn[
 Table[ResourceFunction["RandomMandala"][
   "Radius" -> RandomChoice[{Identity, Log, #^1.618 &, #^0.618 &, ArcCot, ArcSec}][Reverse@Range[8, 2, -2.]], 
   "RotationalSymmetryOrder" -> RandomChoice[{3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 12}], 
   "ConnectingFunction" -> FilledCurve@*BezierCurve, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> Medium], 15], 5]
```

[image]

---

For coloring (as OP wants):

```
SeedRandom[22827]
Multicolumn[
 Table[ResourceFunction["RandomMandala"][
   "Radius" -> RandomChoice[{Identity, Log, #^1.618 &, #^0.618 &, ArcCot, ArcSec}][Reverse@Range[6, 2, -2.]], 
   "RotationalSymmetryOrder" -> RandomChoice[{3, 4, 5, 6, 9}], 
   "ConnectingFunction" -> BezierCurve, ColorFunction -> (Black &), 
   ImageSize -> Medium], 12], 4]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

It's not quite as good as if Mathematica had a "Mandala" command, but there are many named graphs that have quite intricate structures that might be fun to color. For example, those with the name "Cayley"

```
g = GraphData /@ GraphData["Cayley", ;; 10];
```

Some of my favorites:

```
{g[[5]], g[[15]], g[[21]], g[[22]]}
```

[image]

Look at the help for `GraphData` for many more examples.