# How to draw a certain region and calculate its area and perimeter?

Tags: graphics, geometry, code-request

[image: Area and Perimeter]

How can I draw the figure shown above in rectangular coordinates, calculate the area and perimeter of the shaded region as a function of radius `r` of the outer circle, and find the points of intersection of the inner circles.

Comment: Better show some code that you did using mathematica else this is likely to be closed.

Comment: I do not know how to do it, I need ideas

Comment: I know that I should use plot, and that  $x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 = r ^ 2 $ and also that $ (x-h) ^ 2 + (y-h) ^ 2 = r ^ 2 $

Comment: related: [How to plot Venn diagrams with Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2554/5478)

Comment: Added the tag `code-request` because any other interpretation imo would render this question as posted on the wrong site.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because I think it does not set a good example. Although the topic is interesting, there was made absolutely no effort to gain any insight into the problem. Other, not so visual question would attract absolutely no attention and would be heavily downvoted.

Comment: @halirutan I can quite follow you, but where is the difference in principle to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136974/764)? Sometimes it maybe should simply be free market forces: Nobody is forced to answer and the question may well be downvoted.

Answer (score 22):

Show it:

```
RegionPlot[
 region = RegionUnion[
   Sequence @@ 
    RegionIntersection @@@ 
     Subsets[{Disk[{-1, 0}], Disk[{0, -1}], Disk[{1, 0}], 
       Disk[{0, 1}]}, {2}], 
   Fold[RegionDifference, {Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Disk[{-1, 0}], 
     Disk[{0, -1}], Disk[{1, 0}], Disk[{0, 1}]}]], Frame -> False]
```

[image]

#### Area

```
Area[region]
```

> 4 (-2 + π)

#### Perimeter

```
ArcLength@RegionBoundary[region]
```

> 12 π

Comment: why does the code show  that weird angle  at the intersection points?

Comment: @Alucard: Plotting functions have finite accuracy. This can be fixed by adding the MaxRecursion -> 5 option to RegionPlot (perhaps there are better ways).

Answer (score 7):

I would use [`BooleanRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanRegion.html):

```
reg = BooleanRegion[
    Xor,
    {Disk[{-1,0},1], Disk[{0,1},1], Disk[{1,0},1], Disk[{0,-1},1], Disk[{0,0},2]}
];

RegionMeasure @ reg

RegionMeasure @ RegionBoundary @ reg
```

> 4 (-2 + Pi)
>
> 12 Pi

Comment: Thank you all, now I have a clearer idea of doing this with more difficult figures

Comment: BTW, instead of `RegionMeasure` and `RegionMeasure@*RegionBoundary` one can use `Area`, and in v11.1, `Perimeter`.

Answer (score 6):

Your question wants a relationship for r which I assume is the radius of the larger circle. You can get it like this:

```
c1 = ImplicitRegion[(x - r)^2 + y^2 <= r^2, {x, y}];
c2 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + (y - r)^2 <= r^2, {x, y}];
Assuming[r > 0, Area[RegionIntersection[c1, c2]]]
```

yields

$\frac{1}{2} (\pi -2) r^2$

All the shaded areas in terms of r:

```
FullSimplify[\[Pi]*r^2 - 4 \[Pi] (r/2)^2 + 8 1/8 (-2 + \[Pi]) r^2]
```

$\left ( \pi -2\right )r^2$

Testing for the particular answer given by yode:

```
(-2 + \[Pi]) r^2 /. r -> 2
```

yields

$4\pi - 8$

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun. By symmetry we need only consider the first quadrant.

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None], Disk[{0, 0}, 2, {0, Pi/2}],
   Disk[{1, 0}, 1, {0, Pi}], Disk[{0, 1}, 1, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}], 
  Line[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], 
  Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}],
  Text[Style["A", 20], {0, 0}, {1, 1}],
  Text[Style["B", 20], {1, 0}, {1, 1}],
  Text[Style["C", 20], {1, 1}, {-2, -1}],
  Text[Style["D", 20], {2, 0}, {1, 1}],
  Text[Style["arc 1", 20, Background -> White], {0.7, 0.3}, {0, 0}],
  Text[Style["arc 2", 20, Background -> White], {0.3, 0.7}, {0, 0}],
  Text[Style["arc 3", 20, Background -> White], {1.4, 1.4}, {0, 0}],
  Text[Style["arc 4", 20, Background -> White], {0.8, 1.5}, {0, 0}],
  Text[Style["arc 5", 20, Background -> White], {1.5, 0.8}, {0, 0}]
  }]
```

[image]

Let the radius of the small circle be 1 (hence the radius of the large circle is 2).

So the perimeter can be seen to be length of arc1+ arc2+arc3+arc4+arc5:

Let $p_i$ represent arc  i length. Now $p_1=p_2=p_4=p_5= \pi/2$ and arc length $p3= \pi/2 \times 2$. Hence total perimeter:

```
perimeter = 4 (4 Pi/2 + Pi/2 2)
```

i.e. $12\pi$

For the area: area  bounded by arc1 and arc 2 is 2 x (area of sector-area of triangle ABC):

```
area1 = 2 (Pi/4 - 1/2)
```

The area bounded by arcs 3,4 and 5= area of quarter circle -area of 2 semicircles+ area of overlap:

```
area2 = (Pi/2) 2^2/2 - Pi + area1
```

Note `area1`=`area2`=$\pi/2-1$, so the total area is

```
total = Simplify[4 (area1 + area2)]
```

yielding:

```
4 (-2 + \[Pi])
```

Comment: Thank you all, now I have a clearer idea of doing this with more difficult figures

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a Mathematica problem. It is a Euclidean geometry problem and can be solve by a little classic geometry reasoning. Like ubpdqn I will work in the 1st quadrant and invoke symmetry.

[image: diagram]

By construction

$\qquad$OC = OE = R
$\qquad$OB = OD = DA = BA = R/2

By observation

$\qquad$Quadrant perimeter = EA + AO + OA + BA + EC
$\qquad$OBAD is a square

Arcs EA + OA and AO, + BA are one half the circumference of the equal circles centered at B and D, which have diameters R/2, so EA + OA + AO, + BA = circumference of an inner circle = π R.  EC is one quarter of the circumference of the outer circle, so EC = (2 π R)/4 = π R/2. The quadrant perimeter is therefore π R + π R/2 = 3 π R/2.

It follows that the full perimeter, 4 x (quadrant perimeter), is 6 π R.

Point A is one of the points where the inner circles intersect and it clearly lies at {R/2, R/2}. By symmetry, the four points of intersection are

$\qquad${{R/2, R/2}, {-R/2, R/2}, {-R/2, -R/2}, {R/2, -R/2}}.

Finding the area is a little more complicated, but not much.

The area, a1, between the two arcs ending at points O and A is clearly twice the difference of the area between the arc OA and the dashed line OA. This in turn is the area of a quadrant of inner circle centered at B less the half the square OBAD. Thus,

$\qquad$a1 = 2 ((π (R/2)^2)/4 - ((R/2)^2)/2) = 1/8 (π - 2) R^2

The area, a2, bordered by the arcs EC, EA and AC is the area of the quadrant less the area of 2 quadrants of an inner circle less the area of the square OBAD. This is given by

$\qquad$a2 = (π R^2)/4 - (π (R/2)^2)/2 - (R/2)^2 = 1/8 (π - 2) R^2

Note that a1 = a2 (which I find an interesting result in itself). Therefore, the full area is

$\qquad$4 (2 a1) = (π - 2) R^2

Comment: Thank you all, now I have a clearer idea of doing this with more difficult figures