# How can I reproduce this mandala with Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I found this image on the Internet and it is very beautiful. How can I  reproduce it?

The ideal would be to be able to control the colors of the outside as well as the center.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Easiest way: `Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFDeE.png"]` :)

Comment: @Michael E2 , No, I don't want to import the image, what I want is to be able to reproduce it with some kind of mathematical function

Comment: @David G. Stork, No, I don't want to import the image, I imagine you can build it, just like you build a mandala

Comment: @Susana:  I certainly didn't imply that you wanted to import the image.  Quite the contrary.  I was interested if you had done *any* coding.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork,the truth is that my knowledge is limited, I've looked in the posts, I can't find anything similar and I can't think how to draw that figure and even less how to put that green color from less to more, that's why I ask to learn,Anything you can give me will be appreciated..

Comment: see [Code that generates a mandala](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136974/125).

Comment: [Mandala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandala) (Wikipedia).

Comment: BTW, it is the logo of [Corel Draw 2018](https://community.coreldraw.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/845/Capturar.PNG)

Comment: @István Zachar,I didn't realize it was the logo of a program

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Update:** We can get a shape similar (except for colors) to the one  in OP using [`ScalingTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingTransform.html) as follows:

```
ClearAll[t1, t2];
t1[n_: 8, s_: .3] := ScalingTransform[s, #] & /@ 
   Transpose[Through @ {Cos, Sin} @ Rest[Subdivide[n] Pi]];

t2[n_: 8, s_: .25] :=  ScalingTransform[s, #] & /@ 
   Transpose[Through @ {Cos, Sin} @ (Pi/2/n + Rest[Subdivide[n] Pi])];

t3[n_: 8, s_: .25] := Composition[ScalingTransform[{7/8, 7/8}], #] & /@ t1[n, s]

Graphics[{Opacity[1], Thick, EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[5], Green}],
  MapThread[{Darker @ #, GeometricTransformation[Disk[], #2]} &,
   {{Darker @ Green, Green, Darker @ Green}, {t1[], t2[], t3[]}}],
  EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[8], Darker @ Green}], Black, Disk[{0, 0}, 6/8],
  Green, Circle[{0, 0}, 11/16]},
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can play with simple transformations of trigonometric functions to create your own mandala generator:

```
mandala[n_, f_: Sin, x0_: - 2 Pi, x1_: 2 Pi] :=  Plot[{ f[x], -  f[x]}, {x, x0, x1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, RandomColor[]], 
   Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> False, 
   PlotRange -> All] /. 
    prim : (_Line | _Polygon) :> 
      Table[GeometricTransformation[prim, 
         ReflectionTransform[{Cos[Pi u], Sin[Pi u]}]], {u, Range[n]/n/2}]

Multicolumn[{Show[mandala /@ {4, 8, 16}, ImageSize -> Medium], 
  Show[mandala /@ {4, 16}, mandala[8, Sin, -3 Pi/2, 3 Pi/2], 
    ImageSize -> Medium], 
  Show[mandala[#, Cos, -3 Pi/2, 3 Pi/2] & /@ {4, 8, 16}, 
    ImageSize -> Medium ],
  Show[mandala[4, Cos, -3 Pi/2, 3 Pi/2], mandala[8, Sin], 
    ImageSize -> Medium]}, 2]
```

[image]

Playing with `ParametricPlot` and the option `ColorFunction`:

```
ClearAll[mandala2]
mandala2[n_, f_: Sin, x0_: - 2 Pi, x1_: 2 Pi] := 
 ParametricPlot[ {x, v f[x] + (1 - v) (-f[x])}, {x, x0, x1}, {v, 0, 
    1}, BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Thick], 
   ColorFunction -> (Function[{x, y}, 
      ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"][(1 - Rescale[Abs@x, {0, x1}])]]), 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False, Frame -> False, 
   Background -> Black] /. 
  prim : (_Line | _Polygon) :> 
   Table[GeometricTransformation[prim, 
     ReflectionTransform[{Cos[Pi u], Sin[Pi u]}]], {u, Range[n]/n/2}]

Multicolumn[{Show[mandala2 /@ {4, 8, 16}, ImageSize -> Medium], 
  Show[mandala2 /@ {4, 16}, mandala2[8, Sin, -3 Pi/2, 3 Pi/2], 
   ImageSize -> Medium], 
  Show[mandala2[#, Cos, -3 Pi/2, 3 Pi/2] & /@ {4, 8, 16}, 
   ImageSize -> Medium ],
  Show[mandala2[16, Cos, -Sqrt[3] Pi, Sqrt[3] Pi], mandala2[12, Sin], 
   ImageSize -> Medium]}, 2]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** Take an ellipse and rotate it around different points:

```
Graphics[Table[{Red, EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], Opacity[.3], 
    Rotate[Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 3}], t, {0, #}]}, {t, Rest[2 Subdivide[2 16] Pi]}], 
  ImageSize -> Medium, Background -> Black, 
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]] & /@  {1, 3,  5, 7} // Partition[#, 2] & // Grid
```

[image]

We can also get a rich variety of patterns rotating font glyphs:

```
ss = Graphics[Table[{Red, Opacity[.75],
       Rotate[Text @ Style["S", FontFamily -> "French Script MT", 
          FontSize -> Scaled[.5]], t, # ]}, {t, Rest[2 Subdivide[2 8] Pi]}], 
     ImageSize -> Medium, Background -> None, 
     PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]] & /@ {{0, 1}, {0, -1}};

Row[Show[#, Background -> Black] & /@ ss]
```

[image]

We can overlay several of these with different scales:

```
Graphics[{Inset[ss[[1]], {0, 0}, Center, Scaled[3], 
    Background -> Black], 
  Inset[ss[[2]], {0, 0}, Center, Scaled[1]], 
  Inset[ss[[1]], {0, 0}, Center, Scaled[4/9]]}, ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

And last ... a Halloween special:

```
Graphics[{Disk[{0, -1}, 2], Red, Opacity[.75], 
  Text[Style["\[FreakedSmiley]", FontFamily -> "French Script MT", 
    FontSize -> Scaled[.5]], {0, -.9}], 
 Table[Rotate[Text@Style["\[FreakedSmiley]", 
    FontFamily -> "French Script MT", FontSize -> Scaled[.4]], t, {0, -1} ], 
  {t, Rest[2 Subdivide[2 7] Pi]}]}, 
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: Great... (I'd expect no less...) but how does one shade the petals, which is one of the key requirements?

Comment: Quite spectacular!

Comment: Thank you @David and chris. I can't think of a simple way to get the 3D look. Played with `ColorFunction` with gradient color schemes in `ParametricPlot` but... couldn't get anywhere close.

Comment: @David, Simon Woods has this  post [How can I add drop shadows and specular highlights to 2D graphics?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43186/125) that looks amazing.

Comment: @kglr_What a marvel of images you've created, as you would do to put haircuts on the figure,thanks for the links above

Answer (score 13):

A modest start:

```
Show[PolarPlot[10 + Sin[10 \[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]},
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.02], Green}], 
 Graphics[{Black, Disk[{0, 0}, 9]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: at least now I know how to do that.

Answer (score 10):

Taking David G. Stork's approach a step further: Use `PolarPlot` to create pairs of curves and use them to create `FilledCurve`s:

```
n = 9;
a = 1.;
b = 0;

polarplot = PolarPlot[{a - 1/n Sin[n t + b], a + 1/n Sin[n t + b]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   ImageSize -> 400, Axes -> False];

Row[{polarplot, 
    Graphics[{Opacity[1], Red, FilledCurve @ Cases[polarplot, _Line, All]}, 
      ImageSize -> 400]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Layer several of the above with different values for `a` and `b`:

```
n = 9;

Show[With[{pp = PolarPlot[{# - 1/n Sin[n t + (Pi/2) Boole[# == .9 || # == .7]], 
    # + 1/n Sin[n t + (Pi/2) Boole[# == .9 || # == .7]]},
    {t, 0, 2 Pi},  Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[10], 
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, t, r}, 
         Blend[{Green, Black}, .05 (1 - #) + r/#  Mod[t, Pi/n]]], 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False]}, 
  Graphics[{Opacity[1], EdgeForm[], 
      Blend[{Green, Gray}, #/5 + # Boole[# == .9 || # == .7]/2], 
      FilledCurve @ Cases[Normal @ pp, Line[x_, ___] :> Line[x], All], 
      pp[[1]]}]] & /@ {1, .9, .8, .7, .6}, 
 Graphics[{Darker @ Green, Disk[{0, 0}, .6], Black, Disk[{0, 0}, .55], 
   Green, AbsoluteThickness[5], Circle[{0, 0}, .5]}], 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: @kglr_Where do you get so much imagination, you have answered my question, but I have the impression that you have been caught in a creative cloud, if you think of the fantastic serious color gradient, finally ask for a good tutorial in mathematics hopefully in Spanish with code examples.
Thank you very much for your time and help and to the rest of the users as well.

Comment: @Susana, my pleasure. Re tutorials/books see [Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/259/125).