# Efficiently fill sparse matrix involving BSpline

Tags: performance-tuning, linear-algebra, interpolation, sparse-arrays, splines

### Context

In order to implement regularised fitting in 2 or 3 dimensions (as is done say [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176375/1089)) using `BSplineBasis` one needs to evaluate a basis over a set of data.

For the sake of providing a concrete example,

```
RX = 8; RY = 8;
F[x_, y_] := Sin[0.5 y] Cos[0.9 x];
data = N[Flatten[Table[{x, y, F[x, y]}, {x, -RX, RX, 1}, {y, -RY,RY, 1}], 1]];
data = data + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.1], {Length[data], 3}];
knots = Range[-RX - 2, RX + 2];
```

A choice of basis using `BSplineBasis` could be

```
basis = Flatten@
   Table[BSplineBasis[{3, knots}, i, x] *
         BSplineBasis[{3, knots}, j, y], {i, 0, 2 RX}, {j, 0, 2 RY}];
```

Then filling naively the matrix is done as follows:

```
ff = Function[{x, y}, basis // Evaluate];
a = ff @@ # & /@ (Most /@ data);// AbsoluteTiming
```

(* 0.245 sec *)

```
 a // ByteCount
```

(* 2081056 *)

whereas

```
  a//SparseArray // ByteCount
```

(* 68784 *)

### Question

> How to make filling the sparse matrix `a` more efficient in *Mathematica* so as to be able to deal with large data sets?

I am looking for a solution which minimises both the `ByteCount` and and `AbsoluteTiming`.

By construction the matrix `a` is very sparse.

```
a // MatrixPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

so I am guessing it must be possible to fill sparsely the matrix?

**PS:** The answer would be of interest for order order of BSplines. E.g.

```
 basis = Flatten@
   Table[BSplineBasis[{1, knots}, i, x] *
         BSplineBasis[{1, knots}, j, y], {i, 0, 2 RX}, {j, 0, 2 RY}];
```

**PS2:** why do `a // SparseArray // MatrixPlot`  and `a// MatrixPlot` differ visually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sparse construction:

```
With[{xOrder = Ordering[Join[data[[All, 1]], knots]],
      yOrder = Ordering[Join[data[[All, 2]], knots]]},
 With[{xPar = xOrder[[# + 1 ;; #2 - 1]] & @@@ Partition[Ordering[xOrder, -Length[knots]], 2, 1],
       yPar = yOrder[[# + 1 ;; #2 - 1]] & @@@ Partition[Ordering[yOrder, -Length[knots]], 2, 1]},
  nonzero = Join @@ Outer[Intersection, Union @@@ Partition[xPar, 4, 1], 
                                        Union @@@ Partition[yPar, 4, 1], 1];]]

colIndex = Range[Length[basis]];

a2 = SparseArray[Join @@ MapThread[Thread[Thread[{#2, #3}] -> 
          Function[{x, y}, #] @@@ data[[#2, {1, 2}]]] &, {basis, nonzero, colIndex}]];

a == a2
```

> True

The 1st line sorts the x-values along with the knots.
The 3rd line determines where the knots ended up and partitions the data indices according to which 2 knots the x-value is between.
The support of each cubic basis function equals the union of 4 subintervals.

Comment: It seems at least 10X faster thanks